# Color of strikeout-line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to set the color of the strikeout-line to a different color as used by the font-color in the layer labeling settings?

[image]

If yes, how?

Comment: Are you wanting this from the main QGIS canvas or from the composer?

Comment: I want this in the property "Labels" in the Layer-Properties on labeling a map.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so.

But what you can do is add another text box in front, with the same font, strikeout, color of choice, and just spaces instead of characters.

[image]